# 2005 Nissan Altima 4cyl 2.5l Overheating

Tags: nissan, troubleshooting, overheating, altima

2005 Nissan Altima 2.5l replaced leaking radiator, thermostat, hoses and clamps car is still running hot, any suggestions? Just bought the car! I'm towing it to the Nissan Dealership tomorrow for diagnostic hoping it's something simple... husband wants a new engine! Hopefully doesn't need it or should I replace it now so the car lasts a couple hundred thousand more miles? It has 146,000 miles on it now...

Answer (score 1):

An engine shouldn't be replaced for preventative maintenance, unless you are willing to spend thousands to avoid a repair that may be as simple as an air bubble in your cooling system. Get a diagnosis first, then go from there.